How do I prove this statement about polynomials of degree greater than 1?
Consider the polynomial equation $p(x)=a$. Let $x_0$ be a solution. I want to prove that, if $p(X)$ and $a$ have the same sign for some $X\in\mathbb R$, then
$$\frac{a}{p(X)}>1\implies \frac a{p(X)}>\frac{x_0}X>1$$
and
$$\frac{a}{p(X)}<1\implies \frac a{p(X)}<\frac{x_0}X<1$$
I think this might be true only because it works numerically, but I have no proof and I wasn't able to work out one. I thought it might be about the rate of growth of $x\mapsto p(x)$ being higher than that of $x\mapsto x$, and this was partly confirmed by the fact that this is not truein general when $\deg p=1$. Any suggestions? It's probably a trivial fact, but I don't know why I can't wrap my head around it.

You should put where this question came from [the context thing], especially as it was disproved so it is likely not from a textbook or homework.

@Mike I "noticed" this while randomly using Desmos, I didn't think it was relevant to the question, but maybe I should have.

So I think this comes out as a counterexample -- let $p(x)=x^2+1$ and $a=5$, and choose $x_0=2$.  Then $P(X)$ and $a$ are always both positive, so that gives no restriction; so your claim would then say that $\frac{5}{x^2+1} > 1 \implies \frac{5}{x^2+1} > \frac{2}x$, but choosing $x$ near zero doesn't work.
